# Trying to eliminate duplicate markers in GMaps V3 sidebar

Tags: google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing

I'm using google maps v3 API to display markers from an XML document, and I'm utilizing marker manager to specify the number of markers to show per zoom level.

Here's the link: http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/mfr/rec/v2/index_sidebar_zoom.php

And here's the problem. It seems that upon loading, the script loads all the markers for each zoom level together, so even though I only have ~200 markers, my marker array, named "batch", contains 507 markers. When I display "batch" on the sidebar, it thus displays some duplicate markers.

So to troubleshoot this, I tried to eliminate duplicates using a jquery script I found. However, when I alert the length of the "batch" array and then alert the length of the new array (supposed to be free of duplicates), it shows 507 as well.

So, any suggestions on how to eliminate the duplicate markers, and sort them alphabetically to display on the sidebar?

Lastly, I seem to have lost my functionality of displaying more markers as I zoom in while I've been working on the sidebar. Any ideas on what happened to that functionality?

Thanks for any help,

S

Comment: Just changed it to work now...sorry about that.

Comment: So my goal is to put unique links to markers on the sidebar. Markermanager loads a set of markers for each zoom level, and therefore some markers are loaded 4 times...and all these markers are put in the batch array. When I remove duplicates, like on this link: wrh.noaa.gov/mfr/rec/v2/removedup.php, the links no longer work. On the other hand, when I try to just display markers that are on map, I still get duplicates, like here: wrh.noaa.gov/mfr/rec/v2/index_sidebar_zoom.php. Maybe marker manager is displaying multiple markers on top of each other? Thanks, S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MarkerManager is diplaying the first 48 markers 4 times, the first 98 markers 3 times, the first 150 markers twice.  Is that what you want?

```
  mgr.addMarkers(createMarker(48), 6);
  mgr.addMarkers(createMarker(98), 7);
  mgr.addMarkers(createMarker(150), 8);
  mgr.addMarkers(createMarker(211), 9);
```

I think what you want is this:

```
  mgr.addMarkers(createMarker(0,48), 6);
  mgr.addMarkers(createMarker(48,98), 7);
  mgr.addMarkers(createMarker(98,150), 8);
  mgr.addMarkers(createMarker(150,211), 9);
```

And change your createMarker function to take a start and end number.

Like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/wrhnoaa_gov_rec_v2__sidebar_zoomA.html)

Comment: Outstanding!!!  Thanks so much.  I see how this works and have learned from this example, but I wouldn't have thought of it myself. One more thing I'm trying to do with this same sidebar is alphabetize it.  I've found that if I sort it, I believe it loses its connection to the map, because the array is ordered in a way to interact with the map.  So how would I simply display the same array in an alphabetically ordered fashion through my makesidebar function?

Comment: If this answer worked for you, you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.  If you create the sidebar entries then sort them without changing them, it will work, if you do that an run into trouble, that would be another question.

Comment: Just accepted.  Thanks for the advice.  I'm adding a new question about the alphabetizing after attempting several different things.